# apollo-android does not provide variables in request

Tags: java, android, graphql, express-graphql, apollo-android

I used `apollo-server-express` to set up a GraphQL server with the following schema:

```
input IGetUser {
    email: String
    ID: String
    UserID: Int!
}
interface Entity {
    createdAt: String
    updatedAt: String
}
schema {
    query: Query
}
type Query {
    getUser(params:IGetUser): User!
}
type User implements Entity {
    UserID: Int!
    firstName: String!
    lastName: String
    email: String!
    ID: String
    ...
    confirmed: Boolean!
    createdAt: String!
    updatedAt: String!
}
```

Basically the `User` type represents a table in my MySQL database. The server is fully operational. Here is my **query**:

```
query GetUserQuery($UserID: Int!, $email: String, $ID: String) {
    getUser(params:{ email: $email, ID: $ID, UserID: $UserID }) {
        ...UserDetails
        ...EntityDetails
    }
}
fragment EntityDetails on Entity {
    createdAt
    updatedAt
}
fragment UserDetails on User {
    UserID
    firstName
    lastName
    email
    ID
    ...
    confirmed
}
```

**Note** that I have shortened the `User` type and the `UserDetails` fragment.

The query is located in my Android Studio Project and the `apollo-android` plugin generates the Java objects correctly. What I am trying is to fetch a User with the ID 1. My Java code looks like the following:

```
RestClient.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
    .getApolloClient(getString(R.string.urlGraphQLEndpoint))
    .query(
        GetUserQuery.builder()
            .userID(userID) // userID = 1 is a local variable
            .build()
    )
    .httpCachePolicy(HttpCachePolicy.NETWORK_ONLY)
    .enqueue(new ApolloCall.Callback<GetUserQuery.Data>() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@Nonnull ApolloException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(@Nonnull Response<GetUserQuery.Data> response) {
            // Doesn't matter
        }
    })
```

The `RestClient` class is a `Singleton` that provides access to the `ApolloClient` instance and the resource string `urlGraphQLEndpoint` points to the IP address and port of my local GraphQL server: `http://10.0.2.2:3000/graphql`. When I try to execute my Android app I receive the following error message:

```
HTTP 400 Bad Request
com.apollographql.apollo.exception.ApolloHttpException: HTTP 400 Bad Request
    at com.apollographql.apollo.internal.interceptor.ApolloParseInterceptor.parse(ApolloParseInterceptor.java:105)
    at com.apollographql.apollo.internal.interceptor.ApolloParseInterceptor.access$100(ApolloParseInterceptor.java:28)
    at com.apollographql.apollo.internal.interceptor.ApolloParseInterceptor$1.onResponse(ApolloParseInterceptor.java:53)
    at com.apollographql.apollo.internal.interceptor.ApolloServerInterceptor$1$1.onResponse(ApolloServerInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:153)
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

On the server-side I receive the following console log:

```
GraphQLError: Variable "$UserID" of requiredtype "Int!" was not provided!
    at getVariableValues ...
```

When I try the exact same **query**, that should be used by the `apollo-android` client with GraphiQL everything is working as I am expecting and I receive the User with the ID 1. It seems like an internal mistake of the `apollo-android` lib for me, but because my Java code and my GraphQL query doesn't look much different to the `apollo-android` example [Generate Code using Apollo](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android#generate-code-using-apollo) and [Consuming Code](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android#consuming-code) I don't really know where my mistake is.

Thanks in advance, I appreciate every help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the mistake... As you can see in my **query** I'm using capital letters at the beginning of some of my variables. `apollo-android` is case-sensitive, like it should be, but it ignores capital letters at the beginning of variables and converts them to small letters.
With the help of the Postman proxy I was able to inspect the network requests of my app and saw that the variables were still small letters.

Comment: I literally wasted 1 and a half-day behind this thank you so much for answering for your own question.